# sorting a std::map<string,double>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map of time stamps and some data  `map<string,double> mymap;`   how can i sort this by the time stamp so that everything is in chrnological order?
heres a sample data set of whats inside,
  what i have.

```
 < timestamp           ,         data>

"2011-02-04 14:14:51"             1
"2010-09-24 07:45:13"             2
"2011-10-28 11:10:32"             3
"2008-10-27 11:10:32"             4
"2008-10-27 11:10:33"             5
```

desired result

```
"2008-10-27 11:10:32"             4
"2008-10-27 11:10:33"             5
"2010-09-24 07:45:13"             2
"2011-02-04 14:14:51"             1
"2011-10-28 11:10:32"             3
```

Comment: Don't store timestamps as strings.  Convert it to a correct numerical representation.

Comment: How are you getting that output?  I can't think of any reason a `map<string, double>` would have data in the order you claim it's in.

Comment: Isn't `std::map` always sorted automatically?

Comment: @BrendanLong yes but my dataset isn't sorted

Comment: @joe so i would have to parse `"2011-10-28 11:10:32"` as `20111028111032` ?

Comment: No, Joe is wrong. The ISO date and time formats are designed to be sortable as strings. You don't have to do anything!

Comment: @pyCthon: that would be one way.  You could also convert it to a time_t or some other value (or as a double, etc.)

Comment: -1 If you already have this map, wouldn't you have noticed it was already sorted the way you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) should always be sorted:

> Internally, the elements in the `map` are sorted from lower to higher key value following a specific strict weak ordering criterion set on construction.

The only thing I can think of is that it's not comparing the strings correctly. Using an integer or a format designed to store dates may help.

Comment: Well, it's sorted ASCII-betically (unless a comparison operator is specified).  But, as Benj noted, ASCII-betically is correct for this case.

Comment: @MaxLybbert Yes, ISO 8601 is specifically designed to sort correctly in this case.

Answer (score 8):

You're actually in luck because your time stamp is Y-M-D H:M:S (ISO 8601), the time sort order will be the same as the string sort order.  So because `std::string` has an `operator<()`, your `std::map` will already be in date order if you iterate through it.  All you have to do is fill the map and it will order its self.

Of course really it's a good idea to store dates in a numerical or date object format such as `boost::posix_time::ptime` for example.  This would certainly be more performant, both in terms of memory and processing because expensive string comparisons would be replaced with cheap integral comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Just print it out in its natural order, like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  std::map<std::string, double> map;

  map["2011-02-04 14:14:51"] = 1;
  map["2010-09-24 07:45:13"] = 2;
  map["2011-10-28 11:10:32"] = 3;
  map["2008-10-27 11:10:32"] = 4;
  map["2008-10-27 11:10:33"] = 5;

  std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it(map.begin()), end(map.end());
  while(it != end) {
    std::cout << '"' << it->first << '"' << "     " << it->second << "\n";
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store 64 bit representation of date and use it to sort your items or write a comparer that will convert strings to date before comparation

Hope is useful for you.